# Remove a JSON object from a JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json

I have following JSON string:

```
[
{"portNumber":3,"queueId":1,"transmitBytes":0,"transmitPackets":0,"transmitErrors":0},
{"portNumber":2,"queueId":0,"transmitBytes":12940,"transmitPackets":199,"transmitErrors":0},
{"portNumber":2,"queueId":1,"transmitBytes":70,"transmitPackets":1,"transmitErrors":0},
{"portNumber":2,"queueId":2,"transmitBytes":0,"transmitPackets":0,"transmitErrors":0}
]
```

and I want to remove the whole second JSON object from my string (which has queueId:0). I have tried the .substring class but could not find any useful solutions for this purpose. Any suggestion ?.

Comment: don't manipulate json with string operations. Unless you know EXACTLY what you're doing, you can very easily corrupt the entire string. decode the string to a native structure, delete whatever you want from that, then re-encode to json.

Comment: I believe you want to parse JSON. If so, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256669/java-built-in-data-parser-for-json-or-xml-or-else#9256693

Comment: Why the second in particular? Why don't you use a JSON library?

Comment: Hi Marc B. This is also the decoded version. I have used the org.json library in order to parse the JSON String, but I need to remove the second object somehow

Comment: Hi fge. I'm using floodlight in order to monitor my network, and the point is that it automatically fills data in queue 0 (which is the second object here, and has 12940 transmitted bytes). So the data increases automatically in this queue, and therefore I don't want that queue in my JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is in JSON format, you could just parse the json and store the string as a JSONArray and then remove the value with `queueID = 0` from that. String manipulation on Strings in JSON format is not advised and can become complex.

Comment: Hi. I want to remove the whole object which includes the queueId:0